# DateTimeFormatter exception parsing its own print result

Tags: java, datetime, dateformatter

I don't understand something, I have this code :

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().format(fmt), fmt));
```

This generate and exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20200605102607066' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Test.main(AccountPasswordHistoryTypeHandler.java:102)
```

But if I change the pattern to have a separator between date part and time part : `"yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS"` it works as expected.

Why is a formatter can't parse its own result ?

Comment: It works fine with me, what java version you are using?

Comment: check also the [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/wsocHa)

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8u251

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, I didn't see this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in Java8 check this :

[JDK-8031085 : DateTimeFormatter won't parse dates with custom format "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8031085)

It was fixed in the new version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use the workaround.

Comment: or make an upgrade to your JDK @iXô there are many bugs fixed and many other features

Comment: It is more than 2 years than I want to do so :( maybe at the end of the year I will succeed to make the higher ups understand.